# Netbeans "Unable to launch the application" on Webstart

Tags: java, html, netbeans, java-web-start

I've tried copying my project to a new location, messing with project properties, copying the file location and pasting it in the jnlp and nothing works. I'm losing my mind here.

Exception tab:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\Users\ak058214\OneDrive"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebaseEx(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Launch File Tab/launch.jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/Users/ak058214/OneDrive%20-%20Cerner%20Corporation/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CommerceBankApplication/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title/>
        <vendor/>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description/>
        <description kind="short"/>
    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.8+"/>
        <jar href="CommerceBankApplication.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="CommerceBankAppUI.Main">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Did you try exporting Project and importing it again?

Comment: Yup. Same thing.